# Unclear about process state of a multi-threaded process

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

In a multi-threaded system, is it possible to have one thread of a process to wait on I/O and other thread of the same process to do some other work related to the process?

If it is possible, what can be said about the state of the process? Is it in running state or in blocked state?

Answer (score 0):

What can be said?
The wait for next message thread of the process is waiting.
The process last message of the process is processing.

i.e. you describe the state of the process in terms of the state of it's threads.

Comment: I didn't really understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: May you should beef up your question, because, if the above isn't the simplest answer, I'm stumped. Nothing to elaborate on really. You do know a process is a "container" for multiple threads right?